# Does the reduced health from Shaped Glass count towards the Glorious Battle challenge?

Tags: risk-of-rain-2

The Shaped Glass lunar item reduces health by 50% per stack and increases damage output by 100% per stack.

The Glorious Battle Challenge requires you to "Charge the teleporter with less than 10% health."

Does Shaped Glass count towards the 10% health requirement, or you you need to be at 10% of your current maximum, regardless of the number of Shaped Glass you currently have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shaped Glass only sets your maximum HP to 50% of your total HP.  You need to be at 10% of your total HP, not the maximum HP.

Meaning, if you have 100 HP, you need <10 HP regardless of Shaped Glass in order to fulfill the requirements of the challenge.

As it stands the easiest way to get the challenge is to charge the teleporter to ~95%, and fall off the map in order to lower your HP to the bare minimum. Note that you can't really fall to your death, so a couple of falls should set your HP to the lowest possible, then quickly charge the teleporter and you should get the challenge.